# Where does the Northwnd come from in MS's Linq documentation?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm here:

```
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx
Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");

// Query for customers in London.
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;
```

Which is wonderful except this is the first page of the documentation and they are using the class Northwnd but never show you how it is created.

I have

1. my database all setup
2. the LINQ To SQL Classes file all setup and populated with the tables I need

I need:

```
MyDb db = new MyDB(@"C:\MyDB.mdf");
```

Comment: It says here that the Linq To SQL Classes file is the DataContext that I need. The tables are in there. But I don't know the name of the DataContext that I/it has apparantly created.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384511.aspx

Comment: This is bad - it works but I dont know why. Here's what eventually worked: MyApp.mapDataContext db = new mapDataContext(@"C:\db.mdf"); // no idea if mapDataContext is something I made or something in Linq

Answer (score 4):

this is a databse designed with microsoft team for demonstration purpose.
and you can download it from http://northwind.codeplex.com/

Comment: The question (which is also my question) is not "Where do I get the northwnd.mdf file?". It is just a sample file that one can substitute with his/her own. The question is "How should the `Northwnd` class  should be defined?" It is not a builtin type and it is not described in the documentation. Should it implement some Interface? Should we import some Namespace?

Comment: Northwind is a sql database. and those types you are using (`Northwind` and `Customer`) are EntiryFramework generated types. EntityFramework is an ORM developed by microsoft to eliminate the need for using SQL queries to interact with database and use C# POCOs to model database entities and use LINQ to query and update data back to Database.for more info on EF google it and you'll come up with tones of documentation about it...

Answer (score 1):

The Norhtwind & Pubs database is used by MS products for tutorials it exists from a very long time now.

You can search it and download the scripts for it

Answer (score 1):

Most people get it simply by installing SQL Server.  Or you can download it [separately](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23654).